# Setting up Postfix on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix

I am following this [tutorial from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-16-04) and trying to configre Postfix to work properly, so far without success.

It all goes well until I try to list the directory
`ls -R ~/Maildir`

I get this error `ls: cannot access '/home/petar/Maildir': No such file or directory`

I tried manually creating the directory `/home/petar/Maildir`

However no directory structure is never created.

There are not folders - `cur`, `tmp` or `new` inside.

Comment: It won't create directories until you actually *receive* mail messages. 
 This applies for the older-style `mbox` where the mailbox file is not created until the system needs it (to hold mail messages).  Check `/var/log/mail.log` to determine what's going on, and see if there's some other errors with mail delivery.  Note that Maildir folders won't be made until you *receive* mail, so if mail receiving is a problem and it's not working properly you won't get any maildir folders.

Comment: Also, you need to set `mailbox_command = ` in the Postfix config so it doesn't use procmail anymore for delivery (and yes, it's supposed to be equal to nothing)

Comment: I added the line you suggested, then I restarted the postfix using `sudo killall sendmail-mta
sudo service postfix restart
` and now it is all working fine!

Answer (score 2):

What the Digital Ocean tutorial doesn't touch upon is eliminating the default `procmail` from being used.  However, thankfully the [Ubuntu Wiki documentation on a basic postfix setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Setting_Postfix_Support_for_Maildir-style_Mailboxes) *does* touch upon it.

Postfix by default uses `procmail` for local user delivery.  Unfortunately, `procmail` supports old-style `mbox` and *not* Maildir.  We need to tell Postfix to *not* use `procmail`.

Your Postfix configuration needs to have the following two lines to properly use Maildir with Postfix:

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command =
```

The `mailbox_command` directive is intentionally set equal to nothing.

Once this is set, you can simply do `sudo systemctl restart postfix` (or the more traditional `sudo service postfix restart` method, which calls the aforementioned `systemctl` command).  You should then have Maildir working properly.